# Understanding the widgetSelected event and the widgetDefaultSelected event in the swt SelectionListener?

Tags: java, swt, listener

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the 2 methods in the SWT SelectionListener. The javadoc is as follows:

> void
>   org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener.**widgetSelected**(SelectionEvent
>   e)
>
> Sent when selection occurs in the control.
>
> For example, selection occurs in a List when the user selects an item
>   or items with the keyboard or mouse. On some platforms, the event
>   occurs when a mouse button or key is pressed. On others, it happens
>   when the mouse or key is released. The exact key or mouse gesture that
>   causes this event is platform specific.
>
> void
>   org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener.**widgetDefaultSelected**(SelectionEvent
>   e)
>
> Sent when default selection occurs in the control.
>
> For example, on some platforms default selection occurs in a List when
>   the user double-clicks an item or types return in a Text. On some
>   platforms, the event occurs when a mouse button or key is pressed. On
>   others, it happens when the mouse or key is released. The exact key or
>   mouse gesture that causes this event is platform specific.

It sounds to me like `widgetSelected()` is called when the user selects a widget in any way. The `widgetDefaultSelected()` is called when the user is *finished* interacting with the widget. For a Text widget, that would be pressing Enter; for a List, that would be double clicking on a list item; and for a Date, that would be pressing Enter.

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general understanding is correct, though the term 'finished' might not be 100% accurate in all situations.

Widgets that send (default) selection events document the particular details in the JavaDoc of their respective `addSelectionListener` method. There you can read if and when `widgetSelected` and/or `widgetDefaultSelected` is sent.

If you look into the `Link::addSelectionListener` JavaDoc for example, you will see that `widgetDefaultSelected()` is never called.

Comment: Thanks. `widgetDefaultSelected()` is never called? The javadoc says "widgetSelected is called when the user changes the control's value. widgetDefaultSelected is typically called when ENTER is pressed. "

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was looking at an outdated SWT version. My intention was to prove that the meaning and existance of either two events is widget specific. I will change the post accordingly.

Comment: How do I make the callback of 'widgetSelected" get called, when I call "setSelection" myself via code?

Comment: Changing selecrion programmatically does not trigger events. The reason Hereford is to avoid guard code in events like `if !programaticallySected...`. Preferably call the event code "manually" as well. If inevitable use `widget.notifyListeners(SWT.Seletion,null)`.